# Search and replace in a verbatim token list

Tags: verbatim, token-lists, substitution

I maintain a package for the R programming language that contains a vignette which gets processed using the Sweave literate programming system. Now, one of the irks about Sweave is that it always produces output wrapped in two layers of environments like the following:

```
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> Some R command
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
The result
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
```

Now, I would like to collapse this into something that only uses a single environment by tossing out the `\begin`, `\end` commands. Or, optionally replacing them with delimiters that the `listings` package can hook into with a `moredelim` definition:

```
\begin{Schunk}
> Some R command
swe@veSt@rtOutput
The result
swe@veEndOutput
\end{Schunk}
```

I am currently achieving this effect through a hack that re-writes the R output driver when Sweave loads the `.Rnw` file. However, this is proving to be a maintenance burden as the structure of the driver changes with every R release and I have to update the hack.  So, I am looking for a way to attack this from the TeX end.

Here is a minimal example of some Sweave output along with my current method of wrapping it into a listing:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}

\newwrite\listinginput

\makeatletter
\def\startcapture{%
  \begingroup
  \@bsphack
    \immediate\openout\listinginput=\jobname.lst%
    \let\do\@makeother\dospecials\catcode`\^^M\active
    \def\verbatim@processline{%
        % The macro now pipes it's input to our temp file.
        \immediate\write\listinginput{\the\verbatim@line}
    }%
    \verbatim@start
}
\def\stopcapture{%
    \immediate\closeout\listinginput
    \@esphack
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{Schunk}{\startcapture}%
  {\stopcapture\lstinputlisting{\jobname.lst}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> getLatexStrWidth("The symbol: alpha")
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 82.5354
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}

\end{document}
```

In my full version the `Schunk` environment is also wrapping the whole show into a TikZ node, which is why I am using verbatim to write things to a temp file and then read them back in using `lstinputlisting` (listing doesn't take kindly to being embedded in another environment).

Now, in `verbatim@processline`, I have an opportunity to examine things line by line and so I am wondering if there is a way to perform the equivalent of:

```
s/\\begin{Sinput}/customDelimiter/
```

On the contents of the token list stored in `verbatim@line`.  The closest I have gotten is by using the [ted](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ted) package:

```
\def\verbatim@processline{%
  \Substitute*{\the\verbatim@line}{Sinput}{swe@veSt@rtOutput}
  % The macro now pipes it's input to our temp file.
  \immediate\write\listinginput{\the\ted@toks}
}%
```

This gives me the following output:

```
\begin{swe@veSt@rtOutput}
> getLatexStrWidth("The symbol: alpha")
\end{swe@veSt@rtOutput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 82.5354
\end{Soutput}
```

However, I am unable to get the following to work:

```
\Substitute*{\the\verbatim@line}{\begin{Sinput}}{swe@veSt@rtOutput}
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this act of sourcery would be greatly appreciated!

---

#### Update

Aaron's comment led me to discover how to properly escape things like `\begin{Sinput}` so that `listings` will treat them as delimiters:

```
\lstdefinestyle{sweave}{
  moredelim=[is][]
    {\\begin\{Sinput\}}
    {\\end\{Sinput\}},
  moredelim=[is][]
    {\\begin\{Soutput\}}
    {\\end\{Soutput\}}
}
```

When used with `\lstinputlisting[style=sweave]`, this gives the following output

```
. 
> getLatexStrWidth("The symbol: alpha")
.
.
[1] 82.5354
.
```

The `.` characters aren't actually in the output, they are just there to show that empty lines get left behind.

I think I can work with this result, but I am leaving the question open in case anyone has an answer to the general question of "How do I `s/\\begin{this}/that/` in a token list??".

---

#### Update 2

I have been experiencing difficulty with using pattern matching macros inside `\verbatim@processline`. I suspect this is because that macro is executed when the verbatim environment is active and catcodes are all shifted. So any pattern specified when `\verbatim@processline` is defined won't have the proper catcodes to generate a match.  I've stared at the verbatim documentation long enough to get a headache, and I still can't figure out how to set things up correctly.

The workaround I have come up with is to expand my original example to a three-step process by writing the content captured by verbatim to a temporary file. This output is then re-read line-by-line outside of the verbatim environment where catcodes are in their normal state and pattern matching works. The result of this processing step is then written to a final file that `lstinputlisting` reads in and processes.

The code now looks like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newwrite\listinginput
\newread\tempin

\newif\ifskipline
\newif\ifhaveoutput
\newtoks\linebuffer
\def\addtobuffer#1{%
  \toks0={#1}%
  \edef\act{\noexpand\linebuffer={\the\linebuffer \the\toks0}}%
  \act}
\def\addoutput#1{%
  \expandafter\addtobuffer\expandafter{#1}%
  \haveoutputtrue}
\newtoks\parpattern\parpattern={\par}

\makeatletter
\def\startcapture{%
  \begingroup
  \@bsphack
    \immediate\openout\listinginput=\jobname.tmp%
    \let\do\@makeother\dospecials\catcode`\^^M\active
    \def\verbatim@processline{%
        % The macro now pipes it's input to our temp file.
        \immediate\write\listinginput{\the\verbatim@line}
    }%
    \verbatim@start
}
\def\stopcapture{%
    \immediate\closeout\listinginput
    \@esphack
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\def\replaceenvs#1{%
  \immediate\openin\tempin=\jobname.tmp
  \immediate\openout\listinginput=\jobname.lst
  \def\prependcode{}
  \begingroup
    % Xstring doesn't like parameter and comment characters
    \catcode`\#=11
    \catcode`\%=11
    \loop
      \ifeof\tempin
        \immediate\write\listinginput{\the\linebuffer}
      \else
        \immediate\read\tempin to \codeline
        \IfBeginWith{\expandafter\string\codeline}{\string\begin{Sinput}}{\addtobuffer{Swe@veBeginInput}\skiplinetrue}{}
        \IfBeginWith{\expandafter\string\codeline}{\string\end{Sinput}}{\addtobuffer{Swe@veEndInput}\skiplinetrue}{}
        \IfBeginWith{\expandafter\string\codeline}{\string\begin{Soutput}}{\addtobuffer{Swe@veBeginOutput}\skiplinetrue}{}
        \IfBeginWith{\expandafter\string\codeline}{\string\end{Soutput}}{\addtobuffer{Swe@veEndOutput}\skiplinetrue}{}
        \IfBeginWith{\expandafter\string\codeline}{\expandafter\string\the\parpattern}{\skiplinetrue}{}
        \ifskipline
          \skiplinefalse
        \else
          \ifhaveoutput
            \immediate\write\listinginput{\the\linebuffer}
            \linebuffer={}\haveoutputfalse
          \fi
          \addoutput{\codeline}
        \fi
    \repeat   
  \endgroup

  \immediate\closein\tempin
  \immediate\closeout\listinginput
}

\lstdefinestyle{sweave}{
  moredelim=[is][\color{red}]
    {Swe@veBeginOutput}
    {Swe@veEndOutput},
  moredelim=[is][\color{blue}]
    {Swe@veBeginInput}
    {Swe@veEndInput}
}

\newenvironment{Schunk}{%
  \startcapture%
}{%
  \stopcapture%
  \replaceenvs{\jobname.tmp}%
  \lstinputlisting[style=sweave]{\jobname.lst}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
# This is a comment
> getLatexStrWidth("The symbol: alpha")
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 82.5354%
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}

\end{document}
```

`verbatim` works it's magic as before between the `\startcapture` and `\endcapture` macros to produce a `\jobname.tmp` file with the following contents:

```
\begin{Sinput}
# This is a comment
> getLatexStrWidth("The symbol: alpha")
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 82.5354%
\end{Soutput}
```

This is reprocessed by the new code in `\replaceenvs` using the `xstring` package to create `\jobname.lst`:

```
Swe@veBeginInput# This is a comment 
> getLatexStrWidth("The symbol: alpha") Swe@veEndInputSwe@veBeginOutput
[1] 82.5354% Swe@veEndOutput
```

Listings then processes `\jobname.lst` to produce:

```
# This is a comment 
> getLatexStrWidth("The symbol: alpha")
[1] 82.5354%
```

Where the first two lines are highlighted in red and the last line is in blue. This successfully removes the `Sinput` and `Soutput` environments, replaces them with delimiters that `listings` can use to style the code, and leaves no blank lines behind.

However, I really feel like I took the long way around with reading and writing two files. So, I'm leaving this question open and offering a bounty to anyone that can come up with a solution that uses fewer passes.

---

#### Final Thoughts

In the end, the problems I had with pattern matching inside `\verbatim@processline` were due to the fact that I had to supply a pattern that would match both the characters *and the catcodes* of the strings I was looking for.

For those people like me who are somewhere in the transition zone between TeX users and TeX programmers, here are the details: Inside a verbatim environment, the catcodes of many characters are reassigned to 12. This is done by the combination of `\let\do\@makeother` and `\dospecials`. Staring at the sections of package manuals that documents TeX code gives me a headache, so I finally started using TeX compiler in interactive mode (something I have always ignored until now) along with `\show` to unravel macro definitions:

```
grendel:~ sharpie$ pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)
**\documentclass{minimal}
*\usepackage{verbatim}
*\makeatletter

*\show\@makeother
> \@makeother=macro:
#1->\catcode `#112\relax .

*\show\dospecials
> \dospecials=macro:
->\do \ \do \\\do \{\do \}\do \$\do \&\do \#\do \^\do \_\do \%\do \~.
```

`\let\do\@makeother` defines `\do` to be a macro that changes the catcode of its argument to 12. `\dospecials` applies `\do` to a list of special characters: ,`\`,`{`,`}`, etc. So, if you want to match against a string that contains one of those characters inside a verbatim environment, you have to define the your match pattern in an environment where those characters have a catcode of 12.

Leo Liu and unbonpetit win the prize for pointing out how to do this. It was a tough decision to decide who gets the bounty---I wish I could split it in half. In the end, I'm giving it to ubonpetit because they went the extra mile in their example. However, Leo Liu did answer first with information that led me to a better implementation so I am going to go through his answer list and vote up some of his excellent contributions.

The final version that I ended up with is available as a package on GitHub:

> http://github.com/Sharpie/SweaveToLst

Thanks to everyone who answered!

Comment: Potentially related question about combining Sweave and `listings`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9916/remove-beginschunk-beginsinput

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for that pointer---I completely missed that post!. I gave it a shot and it did indeed allow me to remove the `\begin`/`\end` environment lines. However, if there are more than one set of `Sinput` and `Soutput` blocks, `linerange` appears to keep the first set and than disposes of the rest. However---that question did show me how to properly escape things for `moredelim`!

Comment: @Sharpie are you still interested in a low-level token replace routine? I wrote one once... (can be copy-pasted from `\pgfplotsutilstrreplace` in the pgfplots package, file `pgfplotsutil.code.tex`)

Comment: @Christian Thanks for the tip! I will check it out.

Comment: I tried `\pgfplotsutilstrreplace{Sinput}{foo}{\the\verbatim@line}` and it appears to pass the string unaltered to `\pgfplotsretval`. The `verbatim` environment could be altering the input tokens in some weird way.

Comment: @Sharpie I don't have my dev environment running here, but I think that pgfplots expects expanded content in its strreplace routine. Thus, you would need expansion control things (like `\expandafter`) to provide the value of `\the\verbatim@line` rather than these two tokens. Otherwise, pgfplots searches for `Sinput` in the two token list `[\the, \verbatim@line]`. Example: `\def\temp{\pgfplotsutilstrreplace{Sinput}{foo}}\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\the\verbatim@line}` should do the job (unverified)

Comment: Isn't it really easier to do this at the R end; using regex or something similar? After all R is a proper programming language  I have a ConText soln (that uses lua in the background) and I am guessing that is not an option either.

Comment: @Aditya It is easier. It's rewriting the Sweave driver wile Sweave is running that is the tricky bit that is breaking with every release of R. Lua would also be easier, but R vignettes are compiled using `pdflatex`.

Comment: Personally, I would rather use `\write18` to call `sed` to do the string pattern tricks. Or to use LuaTeX. It is awkward to do such things in TeX.

Comment: @Leo That would be my first choice as well! But this document has to be built automatically on the computers that make up the [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) which means `pdflatex` only and no shell escape :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My turn to try something:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{ted}
\newwrite\listinginput

\makeatletter

\def\newsubstitution{\begingroup\let\do\@makeother\dospecials\newsubstitution@}
\def\newsubstitution@||#1||<->||#2||{%
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\subst@list\expandafter{\subst@list\Substitute*[\verbatim@line]{\the\verbatim@line}{#1}{#2}}}
\def\clearsubstlist{\let\subst@list\@empty}
\clearsubstlist

\newenvironment{Schunk}
    {\begingroup
    \@bsphack
    \immediate\openout\listinginput=\jobname.lst%
    \let\do\@makeother\dospecials\catcode`\^^M\active
    \def\verbatim@processline{%
        \subst@list
        \immediate\write\listinginput{\the\verbatim@line}}%
    \verbatim@start}%
    {\immediate\closeout\listinginput
    \@esphack
    \endgroup
    \lstinputlisting{\jobname.lst}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newsubstitution||\begin{Sinput}||<->||Swe@veBeginInput||
\newsubstitution||\end{Sinput}||<->||Swe@veEndInput||
\newsubstitution||\begin{Soutput}||<->||Swe@veBeginOutput||
\newsubstitution||\end{Soutput}||<->||Swe@veEndOutput||
With a substitution list:
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> getLatexStrWidth("The symbol: alpha")
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 82.5354
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}

\clearsubstlist
With no substitution list:
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> getLatexStrWidth("The symbol: alpha")
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] 82.5354
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{subsvrb}[2]{%
  \def\verbatim@nolig@list{}%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
    \StrSubstitute{\the\verbatim@line}{#1}{#2}\par}
  \verbatim
}{%
  \endverbatim
}
\begingroup
\let\do\@makeother
\catcode`|=0 \catcode`[=1 \catcode`]=2
|dospecials
|gdef|bslash[\]
|gdef|lgroup[{]
|gdef|rgroup[}]
|endgroup
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{subsvrb}{\bslash begin\lgroup foo\rgroup}{BEGIN OF FOO}
\begin{foo}
 bar
\end{foo}
\end{subsvrb}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a definition of a `\replace` command

```
\def\stripp#1>{}
\def\strip{\expandafter\stripp}
\def\replace#1#2#3{%
    \ifnum\pdfmatch subcount 4 {(.*)(#1)(.*)}{#3}=1%
        \strip\pdflastmatch1 #2\strip\pdflastmatch3%
    \else
        #3%
    \fi
}
```

To do your `s/\\begin{Sinput}/customDelimiter/` you can write `\replace{\unexpanded{\\begin\{Sinput\}}}{customDelimeter}{\the\verbatim@line}`

Comment: Mmm... `pdfmatch` is something I haven't played with before. It doesn't matter for this application, but I am curious---are these primitives present in `pdftex`, `xetex` and `luatex`?

Comment: pdftex: yes; luatex: no (because it's better to make it in lua); xetex: no (because it would have to a unique syntax, different from pdftex implementation due to UTF-8 and also different from luatex due to no lua support)

Comment: The percent after `=1` is *dangerous!*  It leads to `\strip\pdflastmatch1` being expanded, but if the pattern does not match, the length of the result array is zero and depending on the current memory layout you might hit `Segmentation fault`.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this? The `%Start - %Stop` can be replaced by everything which the environment `Sinput` handles as a comment

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  linerange={Start1-Stop1,Start2-Stop2},
  rangeprefix=\%,includerangemarker=false]
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
%Start1
> options(width = 80, continue = " ", size = "scriptsize")
> formula(mdl)
%Stop1
\end{Sinput}
\end{Schunk}
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
%Start2
> options(width = 80, continue = " ", size = "scriptsize")
> formula(mdl)
%Stop2
\end{Sinput}
\end{Schunk}

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried `linerange` after following the link in Aaron's comment and it won't work. I want everything inside the `Sinput` and `Soutput` enviroments---excluding the environment commands themselves. There may be multiple input/output pairs per `Schunk` but `linerange` only keeps the contents of the first set  and all other pairs are discarded.

Comment: @Sharpie: you know, that you can have several ranges in one listing? See edited example

Comment: Yes, but each range would need distinct delimiters. The only place I can insert comments is in the `Sinput` sections so I'm afraid there is no way to uniquely delimit the `Soutput` using this method.