# Modify contents of environment using l3regex and then write to file

Tags: expl3, latex3, answers, l3regex

I want to define an environment (in a class file, as it happens) the contents of which are both displayed on-screen as they are written, but they are also modified (e.g. using the `l3regex` package) and then written to a file.

My specific requirement is that I want a `solution` environment (in which the answers to a question are given), but the solution has a mark scheme given by a series of `\marks{...}` commands. The version that is written to file needs to have these `\marks{...}` parts removed.

The following mwe code, based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88394/defining-a-find-and-replace-algorithm-using-latex3s-l3regex), correctly carries out the regex replacement that I need in the context required:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3regex}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\renewcommand\marks[1]{\marginnote{[#1]}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{solution}
 {
  \strip_marks:V \BODY
 }

\tl_new:N \solution_text_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \strip_marks:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \solution_text_tl { #1 }
  \solution_text_tl  % Inserts original text in the right place 
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{marks}\cB\{ [0-9]* \cE\} } {   } \solution_text_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{marks} [0-9] } {   } \solution_text_tl
  \immediate\write\answerfile{\solution_text_tl}
  %\solution_text_tl <-- ***Regex done, how to write to file?***
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \strip_marks:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\newwrite\answerfile
\immediate\openout\answerfile=solution-no-marks.tex


\begin{solution}
This line has a \emph{mark} at the end of it.\marks{10}
\end{solution}


\immediate\closeout\answerfile
\end{document}
```

As written, this code returns an error (related to `marginnote`, but really it's because in writing to file, it has expanded the `\emph{...}`). If I remove the `\emph{...}` inside the `solution` environment, then the code compiles as expected. However, I really need to preserve the control sequences inside the `solution` environment when writing to file. I've tried, e.g., the `answers` package (or some other solution like this, all relying on `verbatim` to some extent), but then how do I do the regex replacement that I want?

Comment: Please provide a complete example which can be compiled to reproduce the situation or problem you are asking about.

Comment: Probably generate `\iow_now:NV` and then use that ? Hard to tell without code to play with. (Well, one of the experts might not need the code, of course.) But I take it that you don't want it completely unexpanded. Or do you really want literally `\solution_text_tl` written to the file?

Comment: Hi, I've expanded my example into a MWE. I don't want literally to write `\solution_text_tl` (I can do that!), but rather I want to write the \BODY of the environment unexpanded, after carrying out some regex replacement.

Comment: Thanks. I'm certainly no expert and need code to play with!

Comment: Don't redefine `\marks`, which is a TeX primitive (to be precise, e-TeX).

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

Output to file (I've used `\jobname-soln.tex`):

```
This line has a \emph {mark} at the end of it.
```

Output to PDF:

[image: PDF]

Note that if your command sequence takes arguments, the signature needs to be specified appropriately and the parameters given:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \strip_marks:n #1
```

Otherwise, you cannot pass an argument to `\strip_marks:n. With just`\cs_new_protected:Nn, you could define `\strip_marks:` but that can't take an argument and you can't then use `#1` in the definition.

Also, token lists etc. should begin either `\l_` or `\g_` depending on whether local or global in order to conform to the L3 syntax specifications. I've therefore changed `\solution_text_tl` to `\l_solution_text_tl`. Streams are supposed to be declared only as global according to the documentation, so I've used `\g_` when naming a stream.

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% arara: pdflatex
\pdfminorversion=7
% \listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3regex}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newcommand*\mymarks[1]{\marginnote{[#1]}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{solution}
 {
  \strip_marks:V \BODY
 }

\tl_new:N \l_solution_text_tl
\iow_new:N \g_solution_stream

\cs_new_protected:Npn \strip_marks:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_solution_text_tl { #1 }
  \l_solution_text_tl  % Inserts original text in the right place
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{mymarks}\cB\{ [0-9]* \cE\} } {   } \l_solution_text_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{mymarks} [0-9] } {   } \l_solution_text_tl
%   \l_solution_text_tl <-- ***Regex done, how to write to file?***
  \iow_now:NV \g_solution_stream \l_solution_text_tl
 }
\AtBeginDocument{
  \iow_open:Nn \g_solution_stream { \jobname-soln.tex }
}
\AtEndDocument{
  \iow_close:N \g_solution_stream
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \strip_marks:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{solution}
This line has a \emph{mark} at the end of it.\mymarks{10}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

You can see that `\BODY` includes spaces for the newlines and `\par` for the blank lines by added `\show \BODY` to the definition of `\mymarks`:

```
\NewEnviron{solution}
 {
   \show \BODY
  \strip_marks:V \BODY
 }
```

displays the contents of `\BODY` on the console before passing it to `\strip_marks:V`:

```
> \BODY=macro:
->This line has a \emph {mark} at the end of it.\mymarks {10} \par This line fo
llows a paragraph break.\mymarks {90} That was a line break..
\env@solution@process ->\show \BODY 
                                    \strip_marks:V \BODY \env@ignore 
l.49 \end{solution}
```

where the contents of `solution` was

```
\begin{solution}
This line has a \emph{mark} at the end of it.\mymarks{10}

This line follows a paragraph break.\mymarks{90}
That was a line break.
\end{solution}
```

Comment: The `iow_open:Nn` instruction should be `\AtBeginDocument` and `\iow_close:N` should be `\AtEndDocument`

Comment: @egreg Oops. Thank you. I always forget that TeX does (the equivalent of) `>` rather than `>>` as I'd naïvely expect.

Comment: That's looking a lot better than I've managed so far. Is there a way to preserve line breaks in the tex source? Obviously a double-line-break gets replaced by a \par, but I'd like the output to `\jobname-soln.tex` to be as readable as possible.

Comment: As a follow-up, if (after inserting some carriage returns inside the `solution` environment) I add the `l3tl-analysis` package, and then insert `\tl_show_analysis:N { \l_solution_text_tl }` before and/or after the regex replacements, is see that the line breaks have already disappeared from the token list: have they already got removed/parsed by \BODY?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd assume so. A new line is just a space, after all, as far as TeX is concerned and `environ`'s environment isn't treating the contents as verbatim or anything like that, as far as I know.

Comment: @RobertBrignall When TeX tokenizes the input, end-of-lines become spaces, but if two end-of-lines are found only separated by blank spaces, a `\par` is generated. Characters of category code 5 never get in the mouth of TeX, so they'll never appear in the replacement text for `\BODY`.

Comment: @RobertBrignall Please see edit above. I also changed the macro name to avoid overwriting a primitive per egreg's comment on your question above.

Comment: But @egreg 's comment here is more helpful than my edit.

Comment: So looks like the current approach will never work with linebreaks included, since we'll always need to tokenise before doing the regex. I've occasionally wondered whether there is a way to do what I want with verbatim, something like this perhaps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16299/search-and-replace-in-a-verbatim-token-list